# Ansible: What is the difference between '.changed' and '.found' in Return Values?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I have the following code and realised that under the `debug` section.

```yaml
-
  name: CIS Requirements check
  hosts: target1
  tasks:

    -
      name: Check for CIS PermitRootLogin
      lineinfile:
        path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
        regexp: '^\s*PermitRootLogin\s+no\s*$'
        state: absent
      check_mode: yes
      register: permitrootlogin_check

    -
      debug:
    msg: "{% if permitrootlogin_check.changed %}[PASSED] SSH root login disabled{% else %}[FAILED] SSH root login not disabled{% endif %}"
      register: permitrootlogin_results
```

`permitrootlogin_check.changed` would help to achieve the same objective as `permitrootlogin_check.found`.

However I also noticed that while `.change` is dependent on the state present/absent, `.found` is not dependent on the state and `.found` also does not seem to work with the `state: present`.

Why is this so?

Answer (score 1):

> *What is the difference between `.changed` and `.found`?*

According Ansible documentation [Return Vales](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html)

> *Ansible modules normally return a data structure that can be registered into a variable*

whereby there are **Common** Return Values for all modules and Return Values for specific modules.

The Common Return Value [`.changed`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html#changed)

> *... indicating if the task had to make changes  ...*

in your case within the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

The Module Specific Return Value `.found` indicates [if the task has found](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/lineinfile.py#L567) something for the under `regexp` given Regular Expression.