# Ansible: 'cron' module: Return Value 'stdout' not registered

Tags: linux, ansible, cron

I'm trying to create a cron job using Ansible with this playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: Crontab dosyasını düzenle
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    ansible_job_id: "1.0.0"

  tasks:
    - name: Crontab görevini ekle
      cron:
        name: "Run Python script daily"
        minute: "0"
        hour: "0"
        job: "python3 -c 'print((\"{{ ansible_job_id }}\")'")
        state: present
      register: output

    - name: Sonucu göster 1
      debug:
        var: output.stdout

    - name: Sonucu göster 2
      debug:
        var: ansible_job_id
```

But, when I run the playbook, the task named `Sonucu göster 1` gives the error

> VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!

It seems that the `output.stdout` variable is not properly registered.
How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Not all tasks do return a `stdout`. Have you tried debugging `output` instead? What does it gives? (You should add this piece of information in an [edit] of your question).

Comment: Questions about configuring cron for systems or administration are OFF TOPIC.

Comment: This is a question about an Ansible module and it's Return Values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *It seems that the `output.stdout` variable is not properly registered.*

That is correct and the expected behavior.

According the documentation about [`cron` module – Manage `cron.d` and `crontab` entries](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/cron_module.html), the module does not provide Module Specific Return Values

> *Ansible modules normally return a data structure that can be registered into a variable, or seen directly when output by the `ansible` program. Each module **can optionally** document its own unique return values ...*

but only [Common Return Values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html#common)

> ***`stdout`** Some modules execute command line utilities or are geared for executing commands directly (`raw`, `shell`, `command`, and so on). This field contains the normal output of these utilities.*

Therefore registering the results is only necessary if interested in the Common Return Values and it will not contain `stdout`.

---

If one is interested in further questions and answers ...

- [Ansible: What is the difference between `.changed` and `.found` in Return Values?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73657537/6771046)
- [Ansible: user entry getting added in crontab or cron file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76065490/6771046)